# how to register click listener on drawing manager icons panel in google map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, postgis

i have successfully used google map drawing manger. Now i am facing one problem. in the image two shapes poly-line and polygon are shown. i want to show simply an alert when these icons are clicked that is when polygon is clicked show a message 'polygon is clicked' and when line is clicked it show a message 'polyline is clicked'.[icons image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qD493.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to know when the drawing mode of the `DrawingManager` changes (clicking the buttons is one way of doing that), add a listener to the `DrawingManager` for the "drawingmode_changed" event:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, "drawingmode_changed", function() {
  console.log("drawing mode changed:"+drawingManager.getDrawingMode());
})
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/7f41wx2h/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: -34.397,
      lng: 150.644
    },
    zoom: 8
  });

  var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
    drawingControl: true,
    drawingControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
      drawingModes: ['marker', 'circle', 'polygon', 'polyline', 'rectangle']
    },
    markerOptions: {
      icon: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png'
    },
    circleOptions: {
      fillColor: '#ffff00',
      fillOpacity: 1,
      strokeWeight: 5,
      clickable: false,
      editable: true,
      zIndex: 1
    }
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, "drawingmode_changed", function() {
    console.log("drawing mode changed:" + drawingManager.getDrawingMode());
  })
  drawingManager.setMap(map);
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=drawing&callback=initMap&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk" async defer></script>
```